# Disable Sublime Text 3 html autocomplete in Markdown

Tags: autocomplete, markdown, sublimetext3

I am writing prose in Academic Markdown. Autocomplete can be pretty useful when recommends words from my document, but the HTML tags are very annoying.

How can I stop ST3 to stop suggesting HTML tags in my markdown files.

I have tried "auto_complete": false but this doesn't actually disable autocomplete. Don't know why.

Comment: Specifically this question was to have the autocomplete dropdown box stop appearing. Since I wrote this question 6 months ago, the problem has gone away, but I couldn't tell you what specific change was responsible, possibly uninstalling unnecessary packages ...

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the help from Hansimov. I still had some issues that inside Markdown other `auto_complete` stuff was happening. I found out that the package `SublimeCodeIntel` was causing it. I managed to disable autocompletion for Markdown by adding this into my user settings for SublimeCodeIntel:

```
"codeintel_exclude_scopes_from_complete_triggers": ["comment", "markdown"],
```

Hope this might help someone, who might have a similar problem like I did. (-;

Answer (score 1):

Use `PackageResourceViewer` to extract the `HTML` package.

Open `html_completions.py`, find the function `def on_query_completions(...)` (at line ~200).

Change the following lines:

```
if not view.match_selector(locations[0], "text.html - (source - source text.html)"
    " - string.quoted - meta.tag.style.end punctuation.definition.tag.begin"):
```

to:

```
if not view.match_selector(locations[0], "text.html - source - text.html.markdown"):
```

---

- Refer to this github issue for more details: [Remove HTML Tab Completion #229](https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing/issues/229#issuecomment-341960477)

Comment: This didn't work. I followed the instructions, but I still get html tab completion prompts all the time in markdown files. For example, typing 'div' in a non-source code area gives a prompt.  So I discover there are a bunch of other scopes in my markdown file, I added these to the scope exclusions above: `- text.html.markdown.gfm - markup.list.unnumbered.markdown - meta.paragraph.list.markdown - meta.block-level.markdown`.  It works!  But seems like an untenable strategy, copying in every scope when the annoying thing happens again.

Comment: @Merlin My solution works well in my Sublime (Build 3176). Maybe you have installed some other related packages which override this part of options ...